# How to change type order in PearsonDistribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I need to estimate a Pearson distribution from a batch of tables `tab`:

`EstimatedDistribution[tab, PearsonDistribution[a1,a0,b2,b1,b0], ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]`

I don't want to specify the type, but rather have it automatically picked.
Mathematica does this in the order: 4, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2, and 7.
Is it possible to change this default order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along the same lines as VLC's suggestion:

Using

```
data = RandomVariate[PearsonDistribution[4, 5, 3, 2, 10], 10000];
ordering1 = RandomSample@Range@7
(* {3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 7, 1} *)
ordering2 = RandomSample@Range@7
(* {3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6} *)
```

and

```
i = 1; 
pearsonType = ordering1[[i]]; 
While[(Quiet@
 DistributionParameterAssumptions[
  EstimatedDistribution[data,
   PearsonDistribution[pearsonType, a1, a0, b2, b1, b0],
   ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]] =!= True), 
 pearsonType = ordering1[[i]]; i++];
EstimatedDistribution[data,
PearsonDistribution[pearsonType, a1, a0, b2, b1, b0],
ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]
```

gives

```
PearsonDistribution[5, 3.960577237166583`, 5.1789544794566986`*^11,1.`, 5.123787720579541`*^11, 6.563300151390422`*^22]
```

For the same data, you get

```
PearsonDistribution[1, 0.17852976914824442`, 4.083885578478384`*^12, 1.`, 4.084324691133497`*^12, -9.944999191995846`*^20]
```

if you use `ordering2` instead of `ordering1`.

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly. only one thing: perhaps the `i++` bit should go before `pearsonType = ordering1[[i]]`, right?

Comment: @Valerio, thank your for the accept. [Increment](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Increment.html) `i++` _increases the value of x by 1, returning the old value of x_.

Answer (score 3):

By default the first type whose parameter assumptions are not explicitly violated is assumed and the types are tried in the order: 4, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2, and 7.

You could check if assumptions are met for each type in your preferred order by using `DistributionParameterAssumptions`.

**Edit**

The idea was to use something along this line:

```
data = RandomVariate[PearsonDistribution[45, -80, 30, 30, 20], 1000];

type=1;

DistributionParameterAssumptions[
   EstimatedDistribution[data, 
   PearsonDistribution[type, a1, a0, b2, b1, b0], 
   ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]]

(* True *)
```

We just checked if the assumptions are met for the type 1 Pearson distribution, and the output True tell us that they are. You can do this for all the other types in the order you prefer.

Comment: could you be more specific? thanks

Comment: @Valerio see edit.